# Enterprise - External Task List - Connect to Outlook- setting Assigned To

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, outlook, tasks, external-list

I've got an External List coming from an External Content Type which has Office Item Type of "Task". It comes from an external system which has its own concept of a task, and I'm pulling them into Outlook using the "Connect to Outlook" button.

I would like the Task items in Outlook to be assigned to the user (as the External Content Type is set up to only display the user's own tasks, this should be well-defined), so that e.g. reminders set on the Task will appear for the user (hopefully!).

Can I set an Outlook property to do this, like the ones in the Read Item wizard in Designer?

(I'm lost when it comes to using Visual Studio for SharePoint stuff, although if that's the way to do it, fair enough - but a 'no code' solution would be great)

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?
I'm very interested because i'm facing the same problem...
Thank you
Lukas

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't find an answer. I hope you have more success :)